# Unable to get the Current User's Token information

Tags: c#

I have been trying to get the currently logged-in user's token information using the following code :

```
    [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool WTSQueryUserToken(int sessionId, out IntPtr tokenHandle);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern uint WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            int sessionID = (int)WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();
            if (sessionID != -1)
            {

                System.IntPtr currentToken = IntPtr.Zero;

                bool bRet = WTSQueryUserToken(sessionID, out currentToken);
                Console.WriteLine("bRet : " + bRet.ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
```

The problem is that, bRet is always false and currentToken is always 0. 
I am getting the sessionid as 1.

Could someone tell me what's going wrong here?

I want to use this token information to pass it to the CreateProcessAsUser function from a windows service.

Thanks,
Ram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running this code as a Windows Service or just in a normal Console or WinForms application? WTSQueryUSerToken can only be called by an application that is running under the LocalSystem account, which could be achieved by running this as a Windows Service.

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris... I dint know that WTSQueryUSerToken() can be used only from a service. I had ben trying it from a console app thinking that it is the same for the service as well... I will include this code in my service and get back in a short while...